# Adding New Calculated Column Based on Several Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to this:

| Customer ID | 2021 Revenue | 2020 Revenue | 2019 Revenue | 2018 Revenue | 2017 Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 500000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 38 | 268117 | 167252 | 204544 | 176054 | 121565 |
| 55 | 36607 | 0 | 453 | 232330 | 14126 |
| 21 | 0 | 112110 | 0 | 37125 | 609204 |
| 10 | -148668 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to add another column called "customer status" that is based on the revenue columns that I have. I have tried np.select and other methods, but I have several conditions to check and am not sure how to check them all most efficiently. The new column (customer status) will be filled out with the following, based on the following conditions:

- New - 2021 Revenue > 0 and 2020 Revenue, 2019 Revenue, 2018 Revenue and 2017 Revenue all <= 0. Therefore, 2021 revenue has to be positive and all other revenue columns have to be zero or negative.
- Existing - 2021 Revenue > 0 and 2020 Revenue > 0. Therefore, consecutive years of positive revenue.
- Renewed - 2021 Revenue > 0, 2020 Revenue <= 0, and 2019 Revenue, 2018 Revenue or 2017 Revenue > 0. Therefore, positive 2021 revenue, zero or negative revenue in 2020, but positive revenue 2019, 2018 or 2017.
- Lost - 2021 Revenue <= 0 and 2020 Revenue > 0. Therefore, the customer had zero or negative revenue in 2021 but had revenue in 2020.
- N/A - 2021 Revenue < 0 and 2020 Revenue, 2019 Revenue, 2018 Revenue or 2017 Revenue = 0. Therefore, negative revenue in 2021 and zero revenue for the other years.

Using the above conditions and my sample dataframe, the desired output should look like this:

| Customer ID | 2021 Revenue | 2020 Revenue | 2019 Revenue | 2018 Revenue | 2017 Revenue | Client Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 500000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | New |
| 38 | 268117 | 167252 | 204544 | 176054 | 121565 | Existing |
| 55 | 36607 | 0 | 453 | 232330 | 14126 | Renewed |
| 21 | 0 | 112110 | 0 | 37125 | 609204 | Lost |
| 10 | -148668 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | N/A |

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
if 2021Rev <= 0:
    if 2020Rev > 0:
        Lost
    else:
        N/A
else:
    prior_years = [2020Rev, 2019Rev, 2018Rev, 2017Rev]
    if all(Rev <= 0 for Rev in prior_years):
        New
    else if all(Rev > 0 for Rev in prior_years):
        Existing
    else:
        Renewed
```

The statements inside, such as `Lost` or `New` are of course pseudo code. The code uses `else` to default to either N/A or Renewed, which you have to consider, since your statements are missing some cases.